# iframe in an adjacent display:table-cell element pushes down the content on its neighboring cell

Tags: css, iframe

I'm trying to create two side-by-side `div` elements, but I found that having an `iframe` inside the left element will push the content of the right element down.

Something like this:

```
<div style="display: table;">
  <div style="display: table-cell;">
    <iframe src="" style="height: 100px; width: 100px;"></iframe>
  </div>
  <div style="display: table-cell;">
    <span>Why am I pushed down 100px?</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

This phenomenon does not occur when I use `float: left` elements, or when I use tables. Here's a jsfiddle illustrating all the cases: http://jsfiddle.net/shazow/S6JXp/

Is it possible to have a `display: table-cell` based layout without having one cell being affected by the content of the other cell, even if it contains an iframe?

**Update:** Updated jsfiddle with the accepted answer: http://jsfiddle.net/shazow/S6JXp/1/

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not able to use div floating or tables exclusively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In IE8 + 9, Firefox and Chrome I don't see the div pushed down. Only when I look at it with IE7 then it is pushed down. But that is because table-cell is not supported in IE7.

For me your code works.

To bring the text to the top change this class:

```
.fun-table-cell .cell {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 50%;
    vertical-align:top;
    background: yellow;
}
```

Comment: The div isn't being pushed down, but the text within the div is. At least for Firefox 10.

Comment: Because table-cell sets the vertical-align by default to center. Set vertical align to top. Problem solved

Comment: Ignore me, it worked. Had some of my old code still overriding :)

Comment: `vertical-align:top;` was indeed the key, thank you kind sir!